# Oracle BUFFER_GETS_TOTAL 2000001

Tags: oracle, set, profile

I am checking BUFFER_GETS_TOTAL for one particular SQL at dba_hist_sqlstat.
It executed few times and many of them the value is 2000001.

I am wondering whether 2000001 is a real number? If it is we will try to set the Logical Read limit to slightly higher than 2000001. Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the size of the table is 2000001 blocks and every query executing a full table scan would result with this number.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. the SQL is quite complex and using more than 10 tables..

Comment: I can only guess without the execution plan :)